# Why did Operation Barbarossa fail?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, russia

Operation Barbarossa was arguably the main event of World War - had Germany succeeded, they could possibly have gone on to win the war.

They ultimately failed, but what were the major reasons for this failure?

Was the whole operation doomed from the start?

Comment: I'd leave this as a comment but I don't have the reputation yet. [Dan Carlin](http://www.dancarlin.com/)'s podcast series "Ghost of the Ostfront" is a great place to start if you want a great introduction into the East Front.

Comment: Check e.g. the answers at https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100308095354AAAUptT - I agree with most of the points. USSR was just too large, the winters were too cruel, the Nazi leaders were too stubborn and sacrificed too much, they didn't focus their forces, they were lacking "allies" that have helped them everywhere else, the oil and tanks were freezing, ... I actually do think that it was doomed from the start.

Comment: This seems to be a too broad question. Whole institutes have dedicated whole books to this topic, and the answer cannot fit a single answer at this site. Can you please narrow your question a bit? What have you researched so far? Have you encountered any contradiction among the sources?

Comment: I vote to close because this is too broad. What sort of answer you expect? A long list of 100 reasons? If you know nothing about WWII, learn something first, and then ask a more focused question.

Comment: @LubosMoti and the Russian Empire in WW1 had been even larger, than the USSR in WW2, and have you meant that "the global cooling" had already started before the Barbarossa, so that winters in 1914-1918 were much milder? And in WW1 there was the real Western front during all the war, unlike WW2, and still Russia lost WW1. These "explanations" do not reconcile with previous, the 20th century, history of wars between Russia and Germany and even wars in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment pointed out, there were a myriad of reasons why it failed.  I'm not an expert but here are a few.

1. **Failure of blitzkrieg**, giving the Soviets valuable time to relocate factories and build more and more T-34 tanks, defensive lines, train more troops, and refine their attacks and strategies.  Even though this took years, the Nazis' fate was essentially decided by the winter of 1941
2. **Unpreparedness** - The army was given something like 6-8 weeks to take Moscow.  They started invading in June, and while they came close to seizing the capital, they ultimately failed.  Their overconfidence and short timetable meant they didn't bring any winter gear.
3. **Materials** - Overextended supply lines.
4. **Allies** - The axis allies consistently failed in their tasks, for example defending German flanks during Stalingrad
5. **Stalingrad** - the Germans effort to take Stalingrad was ancillary to the drive to the Caucuses but consumed enormous resources and ultimately lost an entire Army group.  It wasn't strategically important and a complete waste.
6. **Hubris** - Hitler would not accept differing viewpoints and had a false sense that his plans were infallible due to his early successes. He would typically ignore his general's advice.  For example, he would never let his forces withdraw, and if you were promoted to Field Marshall, well that was a death sentence, as someone of that rank was never taken alive and expected to fight until the death.  (General Paulus was the first of this rank to surrender at Stalingrad.)

Comment: Stalingrad happened almost a year after Barbarossa has ended, so it cannot be a cause of its failure...

Comment: Perhaps the OP can clarify.  I assume he means the general invasion of Soviet Union beginning with Operation Barbarossa.

Comment: I could poke holes in this, but they wouldn't be very large ones. Good answer.

Comment: Late start in the campaign season due to distractions in the Balkans?

Comment: @ConradTurner, it might be, but I think this passage from [Len Deighton's "Blood, tears and folly"] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood,_Tears_and_Folly) should be mentioned: "other historians disagree and believe that mid-June had always been the date chosen by the Germans. It was the longest day of the year. and offered the best field conditions."

Comment: John Keegan. for in stance, points out that the date for Barbarossa depended upon the weather and other factors. In his view, the difficulties the army encountered in positioning its units, and the lateness of the spring thaw that year, meant that Hitler could not have invaded earlier than he did.

Comment: That doyen of historians, A.J.P. Taylor, is scornful of the ‘legend invented by German generals to excuse their defeat by the Russians’. He says that the 15 divisions sent to the Balkans were only one-tenth of the total force and their absence would not have been a real impediment to launching the attack.

Comment: The ‘delay theory’ is not easy to sustain in the light of other German activity. For a timetable that scheduled a quick and easy victory, mid-June was a sensible starting date. Besides, once the attack was launched, the leisurely way in which decisions were taken does nothing to suggest men fretting at the loss of a month of fighting.

Comment: Gome said Hitler chose 22 June because it was the first anniversary of the armistice the French had signed in the Compiegne forest. Nor did it go unremarked that Napoleon had chosen 23 June for his invasion of

Russia in 1812.

Comment: Quoting Dept of the Army Pamphlet #20-261a _The German Campaign in Russia, Planning and Operations 1940-42_ "At the beginning of April, immediately after the start of the campaigns in the Balkans, the invasion of Russia was postponed by 4 to 6 weeks. On 30 April Hitler decided that the new D Day was to be 22 June. [See DA Pam 20-260, The German Campaigns in the Balkans (Spring 1941), pt. Five.]"